# MomentJS converts my date to UTC by default

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I got an issue related to momentJS
I have the following date '09/27/2021 00:00:00 'which is already in UTC timezone. However when I use the following function

```
const date = moment(someDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss').valueOf();
```

I'm getting 1632718800000 as timestamp value. But when I do the inverse process I'm getting '10/27/2021 05:00:00 "
How can I avoid momentJS to convert my date to UTC by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment(x).local()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/)

```js
const someDate = '09/27/2021 00:00:00';
const date = moment(
  someDate,
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
);

// get timestamp
const timestamp = date.valueOf();

// revert datetime from timestamp
const dateFromTimeStamp = moment(timestamp);
console.log(dateFromTimeStamp.local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```